# Mutli Touch Query in Android. Detecting when fingers have been released?

Tags: android, multi-touch

Here's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to replicate the Alt+Tab function using my android touch pad.
I have a java server running on my computer and an android app running on my Nexus 7 which sends the server certain touch events.

When the user touches 3 fingers onto the touchscreen, I tell the server to press the alt key down.

```
     if(event.getPointerCount()==3)
     // Send message to server to hold alt key down
```

Now when the user moves a certain distance I tell the server to Press and Release the Tab key. That is shift change the current window.

Here's where i run into a glitch.
When the user releases all 3 fingers I want to tell the server to release the Alt key, thereby completing the process.
How exactly do I do that?
I tried using

```
if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP && event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_3_UP && event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_UP)
//Release alt key
```

But it didn't work.

Basically, I want to detect when the user has released all 3 of his fingers from the touch screen

UPDATE 1.

I've also tried using

```
if(event.getPointerCount()==0)
       //send message
```

But that's not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt doesn't work, because it would required to receive the MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_n_UP in the same event, which will never happens. You receive them one by one.

Your second attempt should work. If it doesn't work, the issue should be in some other part of your code logic. Better to post it if you want a more concrete answer.

Regards.